# Lync-SDK MissingMethod-Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, lync, skype-for-business

I've trying to update your skype for business-integration. Currently we're using the old sdk which is build with .net 3.5. Now we want to use the new sdk build with .net 4.0. So I've downloaded the actual lync-sdk (which is also for Skype for Business) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824 and installed it.

After that I've updated the dlls we're using and tried to run our application. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

To find out what the problem with the new lync-dlls is, I've made a small WPF-Application where I reference the new dlls.

At the moment when I call `LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();` I get the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Methode nicht gefunden: "Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient(Boolean)".'
```

I can see that method in intellisens. I'm a bit confused about this problem.

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

I'm working with only Visual Studio 2017 installed on my computer.

---

The problem is within the Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll. If I use the "old" one which runs with .net 3.5 everything just works fine. Using the new dll I get the Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that the SDK-Installer installed the SDK into the GAC and that was the problem.